# "Every man and his dog" feminine equivalent

Tags: phrases, expressions, gender-neutral

Is there a feminine or female version of *“every man and his dog”*?

> Every man and his dog were at the amusement park.

The original phrase sounds a bit sexist to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some online dictionaries, like Wiktionary, suggest *[everyone and their dog](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/everyone_and_their_dog)* or *[everybody and their dog](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/everybody_and_their_dog)* as non-gender versions of *every man and his dog*. These have been in use for a while. For instance, here is an excerpt from "Reminisces" in [*The Railway Agent and Station Agent* magazine from February 1894](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Railway_Agent_and_Station_Agent/l4mJeHunhZoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22everybody%20and%20their%20dog%22&pg=RA13-PA1&printsec=frontcover):

> **Everybody and their dog** in that town had the 'fever and ague,' and they walked about like ghosts.

One can also make this idiom feminine in one of two ways: switching *every man* or *everyone* to *every woman* (or girl, lady); switching *their dog* for *their mother* or another female figure. Some of these are constructions used to specify women instead of men, e.g.:

> Her scathing observation was that 'it must be obvious to **every woman and her dog** that this is a male document about a male future where Nation-Family-Father-Son are united in their diverse control, and where the situation of women, far less a feminist alternative, barely rates a whisper' (Martin 1984:57). ([Google Books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/International_Migration_and_the_Social_S/l8SGDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Every%20woman%20and%20her%20dog%22&pg=PA46&printsec=frontcover))

Others specify groups irrespective of gender, particularly if *everyone* or *everybody* leads the phrase:

> **Everybody and their mother** was on there. ([Google Books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Fearfully_and_Wonderfully_Made_Diamo/0-KcvMqEOEUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22everybody%20and%20their%20mother%22&pg=PA165&printsec=frontcover))

> 'Everyone and their brother has a gun.' 'You mean **everyone and their mother**.' 'What?' Everyone has a mother, not a brother. That's the saying. "**Everyone and their mother.**" ' ([Google Books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Hello_Herman/XhPgBo05D60C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22everyone%20and%20their%20mother%22&pg=PA27&printsec=frontcover))

Comment: "Is there a feminine or female version of 'every man and his dog'?

...

The original phrase sounds a bit sexist to me." _Wouldn't a 'female version' be equally sexist?_

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's a good question for OP. I'm not privy to their reasoning and thus can't answer.

Comment: Sorry; I'm posting this in the wrong place (though I do query the propriety of the question and thus answers) as comments on the question are blocked.

Comment: i didn't block the comments must be cause its my first question here. Anyway the female version may well be sexist, I just wanted to know what it was, if there was such a thing because i've never heard it in common usage

Answer (score 1):

Google shows some hits for **"every person and their dog"**, e.g. [Central Western Daily (Australia)](https://www.centralwesterndaily.com.au/story/781079/every-person-and-their-dog-will-be-there/), [Newcastle Herald (Australia)](https://www.newcastleherald.com.au/story/5874910/some-dog-owners-should-be-brought-to-heel/), [Barnet Council (UK)](https://www.barnet.gov.uk/sites/default/files/dr_anindita_article.pdf), even someone on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21484215/postgresql-get-last-value-in-a-comma-separated-list-of-values/21485316#21485316). "Every woman and her dog" is sometimes seen but appears to have less currency outside very casual writing (social media posts, etc).

Perhaps a better alternative is **"all and sundry"**, which [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/all-and-sundry) defines as "all the various people, individually and collectively"; it carries a similar, slightly dismissive (or condescending) connotation to "every man and his dog".

**"Old Uncle Tom Cobley and all"** is another (slightly humorous and probably British) expression meaning everyone, from the folk song [Widecombe Fair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widecombe_Fair_(song)).

If you're wanting to avoid the slightly negative connotation, you could say something like "**The whole world** was at the amusement park", a classic example of hyperbole ([Reader's Digest](https://www.rd.com/article/hyperbole-examples/).